# CSS/HTML, pager, dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a pager implementation:

```css
.page
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px; background-color: green; width: 1%;">left</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px; background-color: yellow; width: 98%; text-align: center;">
        <div class="page">1</div>
        <div class="page">2</div>
        <div class="page">3</div>
        <div class="page">4</div>
        <div class="page">5</div>
        <div class="page">6</div>
        <div class="page">7</div>
        <div class="page">8</div>
        <div class="page">9</div>
        <div class="page">10</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px; background-color: red; width: 1%;">right</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QcQYW/

This is when it works good (because there is space enough):

[image: good]

This is when its no good (too much pages, or the screen is not wide enough):

[image]

instead, I want to achieve the following:

[image]
[image]

so non visible pages would be hidden, and an other div (with dots) should be shown. The best would be do it without jQuery, but if so, I dont mind

Comment: don't you think, that even with `dot` same problem would exist when size reduces or m i missing some point here??

Comment: no, those "3 dots" is just one div. Only "dots" (or an image) would appear any time, no matter how page should be hidden

Comment: I edited the question, pls dont close it

Comment: i haven't voted to close...you have gud question, i wud vote to open if it closes!! ;)

Comment: thats why Im surprised, I had tons of "noob" questions, still I got positive points

Comment: use media query and use nth-child to show some elements and hide the rest. Something like  http://jsfiddle.net/QcQYW/1/

Comment: pages still break to more line

Comment: @JohnSmith : i see u randomly upvote anything....thats not a gud sign,encourages even a bad answer!! :)

Comment: sorry, thats how I reward if somebody even adds something... but ok, Im stopping it

Answer (score 3):

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px; background-color: green; width: 1%;">left</div>
    <div id="pageOuter" style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px; background-color: yellow; width: 98%; text-align: center;">
        <div class="page">1</div>
        <div class="page">2</div>
        <div class="page">3</div>
        <div class="page">4</div>
        <div class="page">5</div>
        <div class="page">6</div>
        <div class="page">7</div>
        <div class="page">8</div>
        <div class="page">9</div>
        <div class="page">10</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; padding: 10px; background-color: red; width: 1%;">right</div>
</div>  





    <script>
    var countPages = $("#pageOuter").length;
    if(countPages>10)
    {
        $("#pageOuter:nth-child(1)").css(//Your own CSS for DOTS with important parameter//);
        $("#pageOuter:nth-child(2)").css(//Your own CSS for DOTS with important parameter//);
        $("#pageOuter:nth-child(9)").css(//Your own CSS for DOTS with important parameter//);
        $("#pageOuter:nth-child(10)").css(//Your own CSS for DOTS with important parameter//);
    }
    </script>
```

Here check for the number of pages ,if Greater than 10 ,Then 1,2, 9, 10 Are given Dots through CSS using Jacascript

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for a responsive design.

Have a look to this website:

http://skimbox.co/blog/responsive-pagination-with-kaminari

This part will be useful for you:

```
@media screen (max-width: 900px) {
    .pagination .page.away-4 {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media screen  (max-width: 825px) {
    .pagination .page.away-3 {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media screen (max-width: 750px) {
    .pagination .page.away-2 {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fixed count of child `div` :

[**basic demo to get u started**](http://jsfiddle.net/QcQYW/2/) (*adjust media widtha s per your need*)

```
.page {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
.dot {
    display:none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .dot {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .page:nth-child(2), .page:nth-child(11) {
        display:none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .dot {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .page:nth-child(2), .page:nth-child(3), .page:nth-child(10), .page:nth-child(11) {
        display:none;
    }
}
```